# how to append icon in social menu bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to append social icon to the `drop-down` menu bar, but i dont know why my code doesn't work

Can anyone help me?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("li.has-dropdown:eq(6) ul.dropdown li a").each(function(){
        var thisText = $(this).text();

         if( thisText=="Facebook"){
            $(this).prepend("<i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i>");
         };
          if( thisText=="Twitter"){
            $(this).prepend('<i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x"></i>');
         };
         if( thisText=="Youtube"){
            $(this).prepend('<i class="fa fa-youtube-square fa-2x"></i>');
         };
         if( thisText=="Googleplus"){
            $(this).prepend('<i class="fa fa-google-plus-square fa-2x"></i>');
         };
        if( thisText=="Printerest"){
            $(this).prepend('<i class="fa fa-pinterest-square fa-2x"></i>');
         };
         if( thisText=="Instagram"){
            $(this).prepend('<i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x"></i>');
         };
    });
});
</script>
```

thank you guys i target the wrong dropdown.now it works

Comment: So what's happening?

Comment: Only if you could share the HTML code, we can check if the `:eq(6)` is right or wrong.

Comment: Would be better if you could create a [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net) for your problem.

Comment: Does it complain in your console about this section `if(thisText=="Facebook"){$(this).prepend("<i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i>");};` ? The quotes in the class might be breaking it should be single quotes or follow same schema as the other ones

Comment: You can create a snippet here on SO. <Ctrl+M>

Comment: no it doesnt complain tho. but i changed to single quotes still doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

You are escaping your quotes.

You need to use a singular quote when using `prepend` and a double quote **"** when you apply the class elements.

For example:

```
$(this).prepend('<i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dsbx5b5g/1/

Comment: wouldn't it be better if you use on the html part `"` and on the javascript part `'` like she did on all the others

Comment: @PraveenKumar - no, on the facebook conditional they have a double quote on both which is escaping it.

Answer (score 0):

`"<i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i>"` here you are using `"` instead of `'`

change it to: `'<i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i>'` to prevent errors

Comment: @PraveenKumar no it is not look closer

Comment: @LiWen can you update your post with your corrected code and add the code of your html element you are trying to change